# Find all $(m,x)\in\mathbb{N},$ such that $m^x +x=m^2 +x^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all $(m,x)\in\mathbb{N},$ such that $m^x +x=m^2 +x^2$

My try:
The equation $m^x +x=m^2 +x^2$ can be further written as $m^2 (m^{x-2}-1)=x(x-1).$
If $x=3\implies m^2 (m-1)=6\implies\text{No solution}.$

If $x=4\implies m^2 (m-1)=12\implies m=2.$

Now,since, $m^2$ and $(m^{x-2}-1)$ are relatively prime,as are $x,(x-1)$

But I don't know how to proceed from here.
Any help would be appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: Aside from $m$ and $x$ both being either $0$ or $1$, we must have $m \geq 2$. Can you compare $m^x-m^2$ and $x^2-x$ for $m \geq 2$ and $x \geq 5$?

Comment: The answer (natural numbers) is $(1,1), (2,4)$ $$ $$ The answer (whole numbers) : $(1,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,4)$

Comment: Brian Tung,yes.For $m\geq 2,$ and $x\geq5\implies m^x -m^2 >x^2 -x$

Comment: P.S. I guess we don't get $m = x = 0$. Sorry about that!

Comment: But how to show from my steps that for $x\geq5,$ the diophantine equation $m^2 (m^{x-2}-1)=x(x-1)$ has no solution in natural numbers?